# .htaccess file for pretty urls

Tags: .htaccess, friendly-url, pretty-urls

(This seems like it should be one of the mostly commonly and easiest addressed questions on the web, since most websites have "pretty" or "clean" urls. But in all my searches, it's proven to be one of the most complex.)

In the simplest form, I would like be able to enter **`example.com/about`** into the url bar and have the server return the file **`example.com/about.php`**. As it is, I have to enter or link to example.com/about.php, which is not SEO or user friendly. This isn't about complex strings--the file could just as easily be `example.com/about.html`.

I have some code I'm attempting to use with an `.htaccess` file, but it seems to do nothing:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/$ /$1.php
```

I know that the `.htaccess` file is working, because the 404 redirect I have set up (which appears in the `.htacces` doc below the code I've included here) is functioning properly, especially when I'm trying access `example.com/about` and I get my 404 page.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last rule is designed to match http://example.com/about/ .  I think what you want is

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ $1.php
```

Comment: Oh, right. I think I knew that, but I had tried multiple combinations of things that didn't work. When I ended up with the code I included in my question, I forgot to enter the url with the trailing '/'. All seems to be in order for the moment. Thanks!